# Suppressing non-deterministic behavior in Image

Tags: graphics, image, linux

The following issue is experienced in Mathematica 11.3 on Linux (debian 9) but I am pretty sure it was already present in version 10 on Linux.

The expression

```
SameQ[Graphics@Circle[], Graphics@Circle[]]
```

yields always `True`, while

```
SameQ[Image @ Graphics @ Circle[], Image @ Graphics @ Circle[]]
```

returns a random boolean.

It seems that the algorithm beneath `Image` contains some random choices and this results in a shaky/wobbly graphics dynamics.

For instance,

```
Image @ Graphics @ Line@{{0, 0},{1,1}} ~ Table ~ 10 // 
  ImageAdjust @@@ ImageDifference @@@ Partition[#,2,1]&
```

should return only black images, but on average it returns half of the images with two diagonal lines. Therefore, if we make an animation from the list

```
Image @ Graphics @ Line@{{0,0},{1,1}} ~ Table ~ 10
```

we will see a wobbling line.

Is there a way to force `Image` to always behave in the same way?

**EDIT 1**
Switching off Antialiasing globally from the options inspector solves the wobbling problems but, of course, it lowers the quality of all graphics

Comment: I'm getting different behavior. list = Table[
  SameQ[Image@Graphics@Circle[], Image@Graphics@Circle[]], {i, 1000}];
 Select[list, # == True &] // Length  returns 1000 Trues. (Mac OS 10.13.6,Mathematica 11.13.0)

Comment: I have this issue since many years on Linux. Maybe I solved by setting `Antialiasing->False` in the `Style` of the graphical objects

Comment: I've seen this same issue on Linux before and reported it to Wolfram. I believe they confirmed it was a bug the 1 year+ I reported it. I'd report it again, to emphasize it be an important issue to be addressed. PS, what version of M are you using?

Comment: Please add version and OS to the question, as this seems to be relevant. (Can't reproduce on Mac either.)